# Kotlin-flow: Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm, clean-architecture, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to understand how Kotlin Flow works with coroutines and I decided to work on a test app. I'm using an MVVM + clean architecture. Here's a snippet of my data layer

```
class QuestionListRepositoryImpl(
  private val localDataStore: LocalDataStore,
  private val remoteDataStore: RemoteDataStore,
  private val mapper: DataToDomainMapper,
  private val coroutineScopes: CoroutineScopes) : GetQuestionRepository {
       

  override suspend fun getQuestions(): Either<Failure, Flow<List<QuestionDomainModel>>> {
    coroutineScopes.io.launch {
      remoteDataStore.fetchQuestions().map {
        localDataStore.deleteAllQuestion(). // Error is here
        localDataStore.saveQuestions(it.items) // and here
      }
    }
    
    val concatMapper = flow {
      emitAll(localDataStore.readQuestions().map { allDataModel ->
        mapper.map(allDataModel)
      })
    }
    return Either.Right(concatMapper.distinctUntilChanged())
  }
}
```

Here's my dataStore interface:

```
interface LocalDataStore {
  suspend fun saveQuestions(data: List<QuestionDataModel>)
  suspend fun readQuestions(): Flow<List<QuestionDataModel>>
  suspend fun deleteAllQuestion()
}

interface RemoteDataStore {
  suspend fun fetchQuestions(): Either<Failure, QuestionListApiResponse>
}
```

I'm having an issue in the repository in the lines where `deleteAllQuestion()` and `saveQuestions()` are called. Putting the cursor on any of the 2 function calls shows me this error:  **Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body**
Can anyone point me to the right direction ? What am I missing here ?

---

**EDIT** The implementation of `Either.map` taken from the comments:

```
fun <T, L, R> Either<L, R>.map(fn: (R) -> (T)): Either<L, T> =
    this.flatMap(fn.c(::right))

fun <T, L, R> Either<L, R>.flatMap(fn: (R) -> Either<L, T>): Either<L, T> =
    when (this) {
        is Either.Left -> Either.Left(failure)
        is Either.Right -> fn(success)
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `.map` on `Either`. What is the type signature of that mapping function? It probably takes a non-suspendable lambda. For comparison, `Collection.map` is also non-suspendable, but it's an `inline fun` with an `inline` lambda, and that allows suspendability to flow into the lambda. But if `Either.map` is not inline and not suspendable, then you have the problem of calling a suspendable function from a non-suspendable context. Maybe all you need is `Either.map { it.map { ... } }`, where `it` is the `Flow`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik actually Either is some sort of abstraction whose value can be of two different types, called left and right. By convention, Right is for the success case and Left for the error one. It’s a common pattern in functional programming. 
`map()` is an extension function of Either class, which assumes `Right` is the default case to operate on, so in our case `it = QuestionListApiResponse`. The `map` function is an inline and non-suspendable

Comment: Yes, `Either` is a pretty familiar concept. The problem is, you haven't posted enough code for it to be reproducible. Either something is making the body of `map { ... }` non-suspendable or there is some completely different error that's not diagnosable without a reproducer.

Comment: As a separate thing that may or may not be material to your current problem, ignoring the result of `map` is a code smell, `map` should be a pure computation without side effects. There should be other operations on `Either` to perform an operation with side effects.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik alright. Here's my implementation of the `map()` function:
`fun <T, L, R> Either<L, R>.map(fn: (R) -> (T)): Either<L, T> = this.flatMap(fn.c(::right))`
where
`fun <T, L, R> Either<L, R>.flatMap(fn: (R) -> Either<L, T>): Either<L, T> =
    when (this) {
        is Either.Left -> Either.Left(failure)
        is Either.Right -> fn(success)
    }`

Comment: You should have added that to the question :) But if what you posted is exactly what you have, then clearly `Either.map` is not an `inline fun` nor does it take an `inline` lambda, which corresponds to my hypothesis above.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you are absolutely right !
thanks for pointing me to the right direction